# Why my fragment still exists on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm learning Android and I'm stuck at "Fragment chapter" because of communication between activity and fragment. Let me introduce my problem :

Got a `MainActivity` where I bound 2 fragments side by side, respectively `AlimentFragment` and `DetailAlimentFragment` using,

On landscape orientation :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment android:name="supersk.training.android.gestionstock.AlimentFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fgt_aliment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</fragment>

<fragment android:name="supersk.training.android.gestionstock.DetailAlimentFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fgt_detail"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

On portrait orientation :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fgt_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

On my `MainActivity`, I defined method which overrides Interface method defined in my `AlimentFragment` class :

```
@Override
    public void onAlimentSelection(Aliment aliment) {
        // l'utilisateur selectionne un item dans la liste depuis AlimentFragment
        Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "[onAlimentSelection] method triggered !");

        DetailAlimentFragment detailFragment = (DetailAlimentFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fgt_detail);


        if (detailFragment != null ){
            // si le fragment est disponible, on est en double vue
            detailFragment.updateDetailAliment(aliment);
        } else {
            // si le fragment n'est pas disponible, on est en simple vue

            // on créée le fragment et lui passe l'item selectionné
            DetailAlimentFragment newDetailFragment = new DetailAlimentFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putParcelable(ARG_ALIMENT, aliment);
            newDetailFragment.setArguments(args);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            transaction.replace(R.id.fgt_container, newDetailFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Valider la transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

User process interaction :

1. Launch app on portrait (just list displayed from `AlimentFragment`)
2. Click an item and detail item view replaces my list item
3. Change from
           portrait to landscape (here we can see list at left and detail area
           at right )
4. Click item and `DetailAlimentFragment` correctly updated
       on left
5. Change from landscape to portrait and see again just a list
       of item Click again on item throws `NullPointerException`

On step 5, the way I found to fix exception is :

```
if (detailFragment != null && findViewById(R.id.fgt_container) == null) {
```

Instead of :

```
if (detailFragment != null ){
```

Question :

When I change from landscape to portrait, my `DetailAlimentFragment`still remains but why ? Should I call some `DetailActivity`each time I click on item in portrait orientation?

If you need more samples, tell me ! ;)

Comment: this is  master detail flow. In Android studio you can a new project with the same and you will know whats happening. that may give you answer for your question related to DetailActivity

Comment: @Raghunandan I'm not sure understanding what you mean about new project.

Comment: @Raghunandan I finally found what you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found some useful helps.

In Android Studio "New project", I can choose the template **"Master/detail flow" Activity** to generate useful piece of code for mastering it.